# Make NGINX serve .hbs files

Tags: nginx, handlebars.js

I'm setting up a new server, attempting to serve .hbs files to feed into Javascript and its throwing a 404.

My logical thought was to add to the `mime.types` folder in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`

I went ahead and added the `text/x-handlebars-template            hbs;` however the problem still occurs even after a service nginx restart`

```
...
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;
    text/x-handlebars-template            hbs;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
...
```

I just want to be able to serve `.hbs` files on NGINX!

Comment: The `mime-types` file is unrelated to the 404 response. What are the corresponding entries in the access log and error log?

Comment: Do you want to get something like http://my_nginx.com/template1.hbs ?